# So, "The company's meetings are scheduled" means "someone schedules them (regularly)" or "someone is scheduling them (right now)"?

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles, deverbal-adjectives

We all know that simple present tense shows Routine Actions such as a habit, a hobby, a daily event, a scheduled event or something that often happens ([Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html))

Eg: *I schedule the company's meetings* (a routine action, maybe happen regularly every month)

Now, its passive form: *The company's meetings are scheduled (by me)* (a routine action)

But ["scheduled"](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=define%3Ascheduled&oq=define%3Ascheduled&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3719j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is also an adjective. 
So we can say "*a scheduled meeting*".

In addition, We also know that Non-Continuous Verbs or Stative verbs used in Simple Present to express an action is happening or is not happening now ([Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html))

Eg: *I am here now* = *I am staying here now*.

So, *The company's meetings are scheduled* could mean "**that scheduling process is happening**" or "**someone is scheduling them**"

So,  "*The company's meetings are scheduled*" could mean "*someone schedules the company's meetings (regularly)*" or it could mean "*someone is scheduling the company's meetings (right now)*".

**Note**: [some sources](https://www.quora.com/How-Can-I-identify-whether-the-past-participle-in-a-sentence-is-an-adjective-or-that-the-sentence-is-in-passive-form-see-details) say:

> I would say that native English speakers use Past Participles as
>   adjectives instead of Passive Voice simply for the sake of convenience
>   and simplicity; it’s just easier to say “*the package is wrapped*”
>   than “*the package has been wrapped*”.

But it was written by "[Robby, and he’s a non-native English speaker.](http://englishharmony.com/past-participle-as-adjective/)". I am not sure he is a grammar expert or not.

So, if he is right, then "*The company's meetings are scheduled*" may mean "*The company's meetings have been scheduled*"

**I am so confused!**

Comment: You are correct in that the meaning of the statement, absent context, is ambiguous.  But this is true for much of English.

Comment: I think you're wrong.  I don't thing "the company's meetings are scheduled" can be interpreted as meaning that they are being scheduled now.  "I am here at the office now" does not mean "I am staying at the office," although I could say "I am staying at the office until at least 6 p.m.", but it would be unusual.

Comment: @Xanne, so, you don't think "**I am at home now**"= "**I'm currently staying at home now**", do you?

Comment: I agree with @Xanne - “are being scheduled” would mean *now*.  But the other interpretation is that the meetings conducted by the company are all scheduled in advance instead of being *ad hoc*

Comment: No, Tom, I don't think "I am at home now" means "I'm currently staying at home now."  "staying" somewhere has a different meaning.  I am staying at the Mayflower Hotel.  I am staying with a friend.  I am staying at home today (instead of going to the office) because I am not feeling well.

Comment: @Xanne, A: "**Where are you**?" B: "**I am in the kitchen**", so you don't think currently I am standing or sitting inside the kitchen?

Comment: There may be a basic principle here.  If your rule book leads you to think something is right that isn't, then you have reached to limit to which the rule applies.  Or the book has examples that lead you astray.

Comment: @Jim, then, why don't people say "**The meeting was scheduled (in the past, maybe)**" but "**The meeting is scheduled**"?

Comment: Tom, you're applying rules as though they were mathematical formulas.  You may be standing in the kitchen.  You may be lying on the floor or on a ladder changing a light bulb. "I am staying in the kitchen" means you're not going to come out of the kitchen.

Comment: @Xanne, maybe, the problem is not the rule of the book, but native may not follow grammar. So they may loosely mean "*The meeting is scheduled*" =   "*The meeting was scheduled*". Some sources say "*The meeting is scheduled*"="*The meeting has been scheduled*"

Comment: "The meeting is scheduled" does not mean "the meeting is being scheduled right now," which is your contention.  I think this is going to get moved to chat.  Fine with me.

Comment: @Tom - In fact they say both.  The meeting is scheduled for tomorrow morning and you can’t skip it for Mary’s meeting- This meeting was scheduled over two months ago.

Comment: @Jim, "*2 months ago, this meeting was scheduled for tomorrow morning*". By the way, Some sources say "*The meeting is scheduled*"="*The meeting has been scheduled*" but I haven't seen any grammar book discuss that.

Comment: @Tom, it looks like you might still be thinking of "be" as simple present, implying habitual activity, which is incorrect.  You also seem to suggest that "be" is present continuous, which is incorrect.  "I am here now" refers only to now.  "The company's meetings are scheduled" is ambiguous.  It could mean either that the policy is to not have unscheduled meetings, or it could mean that the task of scheduling some collection of meetings has been completed.

Comment: @Xanne  - No, "I'm at home now" means that I'm finally comfortable with using this new computer.  (And a dozen other things.)

Comment: @HotLicks The New Standard Revised Definitive Usage Guide should have a chapter "At Home with Hotlicks."

Comment: @Xanne - Authoritative Version, Premium Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Hearing a statement like "the company's meetings are scheduled", *without any agent being specified*, there are two likely interpretations, depending partially on whether "the company's meetings" refers to some finite group of meetings already under discussion, or not.

The first interpretation, which is more likely if there is a finite group of meetings, is that the meetings have been scheduled for some particular time — that is, they have a place on the schedule, and we know when they are going to occur. This is a common adjectival use of "scheduled", and we use the present ("are scheduled") because the property of *scheduled-ness* applies right now. Saying "the meetings have been scheduled" means basically the same thing. If we were talking about a single meeting, instead, this would be the only likely option.

The second interpretation, which is more likely if the meetings are a more indistinct collection, is that the meetings are *generally* scheduled, rather than happening at any old time. You can look at this as a participle indicating habitual action, or an adjective applying to a class; I don't think it makes any difference either way.

Your alternative of "someone is scheduling the meetings right now" isn't supportable at all, in my opinion. That would usually be phrased as "the meetings are *being* scheduled", not "the meetings are scheduled". The progressive aspect of "being" highlights the ongoing action.

Comment: a source say "The meeting is scheduled" = "The meeting has been scheduled" but that source was written by a non-native. I am not sure I can trust it. Your answer may say the same thing, but you didn't explain why "is scheduled" = "has been scheduled"

Answer (score 1):

The questioner writes:

"The company's meetings are scheduled" could mean "someone schedules the company's meetings (regularly)" or it could mean "someone is scheduling the company's meetings (right now)".

It means, as @hobbs states, either that it's company policy to schedule meetings, or a set of meetings has been scheduled in advance.

It doesn't mean, or even suggest, that meetings are being scheduled right now.

It is idiomatic to speak of schedules in the present tense. Note that using "was scheduled" implies that the event is no longer on the schedule or has been moved.

The flight *is scheduled* to arrive at 4 p.m.

The flight *was scheduled* to arrive at 4 p.m., *but it has been delayed.*

The flight leaves at 8 p.m.  The flight is scheduled to leave at 8 p.m.  The flight will leave (you hope!) at 8 p.m.

Departure time is 8 p.m. Arrival time is 10 p.m.

Departure time *has been scheduled* for 8 p.m.  This use is, however, unusual.

The meeting was scheduled for Tuesday, but it has been moved to Thursday. It is now scheduled for Thursday.

The meeting of the policy group is scheduled for 10 a.m. every day.

The directors' meeting is on the schedule for October, but the speakers have not yet been scheduled.  We are scheduling them now.  Even as we speak, they are being scheduled.

Our lunch is on my calendar for Wednesday.  Do you want to change it?

The poster cites a source for the idea that [there are] *Non-Continuous Verbs or Stative verbs used in Simple Present to express an action is happening or is not happening now*, but this concept does not apply to the statement "The company's meetings are scheduled."

Specifically, the jump from "I am here now" to "I am staying here now" is incorrect.  "Staying" has a sense of remaining somewhere, perhaps overnight.

The following are idiomatic American English sentences:

I am going to Washington.  I will be staying with friends.  I am staying with friends (even if this a trip in the future).

I am in Washington.  I am staying at the Mayflower Hotel.

I am in a bar on 42nd and Broadway.  I am staying here until it stops raining.

Are you doing anything on New Year's Eve?  No, I am staying home.

I am staying home today *instead of going to the office* because the snow is too heavy for driving.

I am in the kitchen.  I am staying in the kitchen *until* the dog stops barking.

Are you staying home tonight?  No, I am going to the movies.

Comment: Your answer brings no light to the question and it is not very clear. This person had a better explanation http://englishharmony.com/past-participle-as-adjective/.

Comment: You are always free to write your own answer and select it.